# PHP code devided by html code doesn't work

Tags: php, html, wamp

I'm not sure if this is an issue with WAMP but I have been having issues with php variables not being saved. Here is an example:

**Works:**

```
<?php 
 $x = "Hellow Wolrd!";
 echo $x;
?>
```

> Hellow Wolrd!

**Doesn't Work:**

```
<?php 
 $x = "Hellow Wolrd!";
?>
<html>
<body> 
<?php echo $x;?>
</body>
</html>
```

> 

Comment: RickyTamma What is the extension of second-code-file? `.php` or `.html`?

Comment: If it was `.html` surely the `php` code wouldn't run in the first place?

Comment: The extension is .php

Comment: @RickyTamma  both codes are in two different files? Or you just trying them in one file?

Comment: @RickyTamma you getting blank page or ?

Comment: The problem was solved. It ended up being short tag not being enabled.

Comment: Testing on mamP local server, it's working fine. Are you trying on a local server ?

Comment: @RickyTamma but in your question you're **not** using short tag, that would be `<?` instead of `<?php`!?

Comment: @xander No I wasn't, someone mentioned it, I turned it on, tested it and it worked. I call that a solution!

Comment: OMG magic is happening here

Comment: you didn't post short tag syntax here, yet you say it was so I closed the question --- *"The problem was solved. It ended up being short tag not being enabled. – RickyTamma 49 mins ago"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blank page is either generated because the page extension is not PHP or because of a typing error in your PHP code. Try turning on error reporting on top of your PHP file by adding this as the first lines:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Perhaps you forgot a simple semicolon or bracket somewhere. Error reporting would hint you what lines you should check.